# How Does the Bing Scout Service works in Wp7?

Tags: bing-api

I am having an app where I want to use the bing’s scout feature available in Windows Phone 7. Can anyone tell me how can I implement it (what all service/api s are needed) or point me to some resource where I can find enough information.

Answer (score 0):

BingMapsTask will do the job, and you must either declare a SearchTerm or Center parameter for it to work properly.